# Is there any feature in android studio that your text cursor automatically go to the code that will triggered while your project is running?

Tags: android-studio

Is there any feature in android studio that your text cursor automatically go to the code that will triggered while your project is running?

Comment: What are you actually trying to accomplish here? A feature like that would flash through code faster than you could read, so I'm not sure what it would buy you. Is there some way a traditional debugger is failing you?

Comment: I'm currently continuing a existing app, and I'm having a hard time to locate all function where it located to the code, and having a hard time also to read the code. Sorry I'm a newbiee.

Comment: Choose a method, then right-click it to open a context-sensitive menu and select "Find Usages (Alt+F7)." This will return a list of all codes that use the method.